# Is there a way to install dependencies from a package.json file into a different directory?

Tags: json, node.js, git

I'm wondering if there is a way for the dependencies of a package.json file into a different directory. Scenario is this:

I have a project that I'm deploying with git and and `post-receive` hook. When I want to deploy my project, I push it to the bare git repo on my server, which then clones the repo into a separate folder (thus making the files available), runs `npm install` to install the dependencies, runs the build (in this case `grunt`), moves the build file to the folder being hosted by the web server, overwriting any older files, and then proceeds to clean up the cloned folder by removing it.

Unfortunately, this also has the side effect of wiping out the `node_modules` folder which means that a fresh set of dependencies must be installed on the next build which takes time if I'm trying to deploy quickly.

The reason behind my question is essentially wondering if there is a more graceful solution than what I have currently. Is there a way that I could install the dependencies to a dependencies directory on my server and then run all the builds from there? That way I could keep all of my modules in 1 place and have other builds that I run on my server use those packages as well, while also adding any additional dependencies that **they** require.

My research so far has not proven successful—  I tried running

```
npm install /some_folder --prefix /other_folder
```

but that had the adverse effect of creating a directory structure that looked like this:

```
/
├── some_folder
|  ├── <various files>
|  └── package.json
└── other_folder
   └── node_modules/
      └── some_folder/
         ├── <various files from first folder>
         ├── package.json
         └── node_modules/
```

which wouldn't really work for having a central dependencies directory.

I also found 1 question that talked about using symbolic links. How would that work?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#node-modules-is-the-name-of-my-deity-s-arch-rival-and-a-forbidden-word-in-my-religion-can-i-configure-npm-to-use-a-different-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you actually want is to have a local package cache on your build server. NPM *[already](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache)* does this. However, by default:

> Commands that make non-essential registry requests (such as search and
>   view, or the completion scripts) generally specify a minimum timeout.
>   If the .cache.json file is younger than the specified timeout, then
>   they do not make an HTTP request to the registry.

This does not include package installs. You can circumvent this by doing the following:

```
npm --cache-min 9999999 install <package-name>
```

There are [few](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2568) requests to have a nicer interface to this command as it's a pretty common requirement.

There are also a couple of projects that provide alternative mechanisms:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache - provides an alternative command that caches packages locally
- http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/ - effectively an internal package registry server

Comment: Would caching the packages essentially circumvent waiting on subsequent `npm install`s? If my question wasn't clear enough, I'm simply trying to avoid going through installing a fresh set of dependencies every time, as the whole build environment is trashed on the conclusion of the build so that there aren't conflicts the next time the repo is cloned in. My assumption was that the best fix was to put the node_modules folder elsewhere so that it wouldn't be trashed with the build files and could then be used again for subsequent builds.

Comment: Yes, that's right.The advantage to the caching is that it makes it transparent to your build process. For example using the `--cache-min` switch, `npm install` will still call out to the registry if the package is not in cache. That's something you don't want to manage yourself as it increases the complexity of your build.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for all your help. I ended up checking out `npm-cache` to cache my packages and it's working great. My build times are now about 20 seconds faster than they were before. Marking as correct :)